# Replacing dataframe column values from a re.search loop

Tags: python, regex, pandas

How can I replace the values of an existing dataframe column with the values from the re.search loop?

This is my re.search loop.

```
for i in dataset['col1']:
    clean = re.search('(nan|[0-9]{1,4})([,.][0-9]{1,4})?', i)
    print(clean.group())
```

This is the sample data set (dataset)

```
    year    col1
1    2001    10.563\D
2    2002    9.540\A
3    2003    4.674\G
4    2004    3.2754\u
5    2005    nan\x
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: year    col1
1    2001    10.563
2    2002    9.540
3    2003    4.674
4    2004    3.2754
5    2005    nan

Comment: basically remove the \ and the letters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to apply the custom function to the `dataset["col1"]`. Or, better you can use [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the pattern with the replacement string.

**Try this:**

```
def func(i):
    clean = re.search('(nan|[0-9]{1,4})([,.][0-9]{1,4})?', i)
    return clean.group()

dataset["col1"] = dataset["col1"].apply(func)
```

OR Better,

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace(r'(.*?)(\\.*?$)', r"\1")
```

**Output**:

```
>>> print(dataset)

   year    col1
0  2001  10.563
1  2002   9.540
2  2003   4.674
3  2004  3.2754
4  2005     nan
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I want to understand the second code you shared. why did you replace it with \1? or did I understand the code correct?

Comment: @Lara `\1` is just a way to reference the first capturing group in the the pattern which is `(.*?)` which represents  the data you want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

Using your method:

```py
dataset["col1"] = dataset["col1"].apply(lambda x: re.search('(nan|[0-9]{1,4})([,.][0-9]{1,4})?', x).group())
```

though personally, I would do this instead:

```py
dataset["col1"] = dataset["col1"].str[:-2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas [str extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), with a look ahead assertion - it will keep only items before the '\'

```
  df['cleaned'] = df["col1"].str.extract(r'(.*(?=\\))')

     year   col1        cleaned
1   2001    10.563\D    10.563
2   2002    9.540\A     9.540
3   2003    4.674\G     4.674
4   2004    3.2754\u    3.2754
5   2005    nan\x       nan
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `split` function rather than longer regular expressions patterns in this case:

```
dataset['col1'] = dataset['col1'].str.split('\\').str[0]
```

or, to `split` into `float` data type:

```
dataset['col1'] = dataset['col1'].str.split('\\').str[0].astype(float)
```

This would transform these values in place, and is not error prone. It simply always takes the first element from the resulting array in case a backslash exists.

Result:

```
   year    col1
0  2001  10.563
1  2002   9.540
2  2003   4.674
3  2004  3.2754
4  2005     nan
```

Comment: thanks for this! I can also use this but how do I make the str into float after splitting?

Comment: @lara, if this worked for you, please let me know. Also you must not forget to appreaciate the effort from others. Either by upvoting informative and helpfull answers and/or accepting the answer that solved your issue.

Comment: yes just tried this now and it worked fine. thanks for the help! :)